# Moment.js format for Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've been tasked with making an input where the user can input days and hh:mm:ss in one field as dd:hh:mm:ss, but going through the Moment.js docs such a format doesn't appear to exist. Is there a way for me to make my own workaround?

Update:

I found a way to format the string exactly how I want using duration: `moment.duration(
    days + '.' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + sec).format('dd HH:mm:ss'));` (it's ugly but I can fix this part later, what matters is it works).

I created the element to be displayed in html using:

`const input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('data-inputmask', '"alias": "datetime", "placeholder": "_", "inputFormat": "dd HH:MM:ss"');
input.value = value;`

This produces an input value that looks like this: `01 00:00:00`, however when I try to erase the date field (`01`), it cycles back to the last day of the previous month.

[Example](https://i.gyazo.com/0a60137e8a2c93aea77630a8147f10a5.mp4)

I need the result to be `__ 00:00:00` (`_` is my placeholder for empty values in the field) or I need to remove the ability to erase that field when the date is at `01`

Update 2:

It seems like I can achieve the desired result by using `input.setAttribute('data-inputmask', '"alias": "datetime", "placeholder": "_", "inputFormat": "yy HH:MM:ss"');`, but is there a more elegant way of setting the inputFormat attribute? I don't want to use `yy` to set my day value.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the tokens that moment.js provides to display time and date as you desire like for your case:

```
moment().format("dddd, h:mm:ss");
```

I have linked the displaying portion of the docs you can find more ways there as well.
[More Info here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the days 'manual';

After the input was altered;

1. Remove the days
2. Create momentjs object with the desired time
3. [Add the number of days to the input](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/): `.add(n, 'days')`

```js
// 12 days from now @ 13:30:00
console.log(format('12:13:30:00'));

// 120 days from now @ 12:11:11
console.log(format('120:12:11:11'));

// -1 days (yesterday) @ 10:00:00
console.log(format('-1:10:00:00'));

function format(input) {

    // Get number of days
    let days = input.substr(0, input.indexOf(':'));
    
    // Create momentjs
    let mom = new moment(input.replace(days, ''), 'HH:mm:SS')
    
    // Add days
    mom.add(days, 'days');
    
    // Return human readable
    return mom.format('lll');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Provide your custom format as the second parameter (*format*)  to create an `momentjs` object based on your user format.
`momentjs` [String + Format](http://Read%20more%20about%20formatting%20momentjs%20[here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/));

Comment: I need the day field to be just a number of days instead of the actual date. Would that be possible?

        ``moment().startOf('month').seconds(value).format('DD HH:mm:ss');``

Currently I have this which formats it the way I want it to, but I need the default value of DD to be 0 instead of 1.

Right now it prints ``01 00:00:00`` when I need the default to be ``00 00:00:00``

Comment: Yea, it's a `1` because `.startOf('month')` moves the object to the first day. So your user input could be somethinig like this: `127:11:11:11`, 127 days at `11:11:11` hms? Don't think that possible with momentjs. I;ll guess you'll need to parse the days with javascript instead.

Comment: @Azuzu Something like this? [https://jsfiddle.net/zbm6Lexg/](https://jsfiddle.net/zbm6Lexg/) (simplified)

Comment: Not quite, however if we go back to the usage of startOf('month'), if there's a way to prevent the day from cycling back to the last day of the previous month, then the above solution I have would work with some minor adjustments in other areas of the menu it's going into.

For some reason if I hit backspace on the ``01`` in ``01 00:00:00`` it turns into ``30 00:00:00`` instead of ``__ 00:00:00``, with ``_`` being my placeholder value.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to explain. It's defiantly possible with momentjs. I guess you should edit the question, add more information about your real situation. Some examples might help.

Comment: I updated the question with an example, I hope that helps describe my situation

Comment: @Azuzu I've edited my answer, does this answer your question?